# Flexbox margin between boxes

Tags: css, flexbox, margins

I know margins between flexboxes can be set automatically thanks to the the `align-content` property, but I need it to be fixed margin set in px. I am looking for something similar to `column-gap` for multi-columns.

Here is what I need to do:

[image: demo]

Here the space between 1,2,3 and 4,5 is equal, let’s say 30px. Any idea?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626685/is-there-any-better-way-to-control-distance-between-flexbox-items-than-margin ?

Comment: Thank you but I need it to work on several lines, with an undefined number of colums

Comment: have a look at my answer, maybe it will help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41033768/1204902

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A solution could be to use margins, and negative margins on the container (which requires an extra wrapper).

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/gozup/1/edit?html,css,output

**HTML**

```
<wrapper>
  <container>
    <column>1</column>
  </container>
</wrapper>
```

**CSS**

```
wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 250px;
}
container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -25px;
}
column {
  flex: 0 1 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 25px;
}
```