# Using flexbox to make a variable width grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a project going that requires me to construct, using flexbox, a grid of variable width buttons, that all have the same height, and are separated by a certain amount of space.

Currently, I'm spacing each button with `margin: 10px 0 0 10px`, which of course will be the reason why I'm having a problem.
Please take a look at my JSFiddle to see what my full code is: https://jsfiddle.net/m025v4uL/1/

I've got it functioning almost perfectly, but I can't seem to get rid of the margin created space to the immediate top and left of the button area, if you see here:

[image: Three images]

It also works perfectly for this, with the same issue:

[image: Two images]

And for this (same issue, and the overlap down is intentional and will be utilized!):

[image: Overlapping]

What I want is to have space *between* the buttons, but not *around* the buttons. I am certain I'm missing the obvious here, and I really hope someone can help.

Comment: Do you need to have an exact, set amount of space between the objects or can that space flex?

Comment: This question might answer yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626685/is-there-any-better-way-to-control-distance-between-flexbox-items-than-margin

Comment: For the purposes of the project, it needs an exact amount of space, 10px. I took a look at that question and it partially resolves the problem, but there is now a weird small margin around the outside, where I wanted no margin. https://jsfiddle.net/m025v4uL/2/

Comment: I can get rid of the left/right with a negative margin on another wrapper but getting rid of the top/bottom is another story. https://jsfiddle.net/m025v4uL/3/