# Flexbox with Padding and Margins

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it safe/acceptable when using flex containers to also use margin-top(bottom, left, right) and padding to shift a little space either, in between elements or to the left/right? Or is it better to use the flex-basis in combination with defined widths?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by 'safe', 'acceptable', and 'better'? Safe from what? Better how?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626685/better-way-to-set-distance-between-flexbox-items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better way to put your question is

**Is margin & padding a "flex-way" to arrange elements inside a flex container?** - Still doesn't make much sense but I guess the answer should explain why.

**Answer**

Flexbox(flexible box) is a layout concept & just provides a more efficient way to lay out & distribute space among its elements inside a flex container & gives you extra power to control your elements with unique properties like `order`, `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` etc. - Very similar to what a grid layout does. Now you wouldn't ask a question like - *"Can you use grid frameworks like Bootstrap along with margin/padding?"* would you?

A simple answer to your question - **Ofcourse you can, it all depends on your requirements. Its subjective not wrong/right to use them with flex**. So yes, you definitely can use margin/padding in conjuncture with Flexbox and if your requirements demands it(which most of the time is the case) or you could just go complete "flex-way" using `flex-basis`(similar to `width`) etc. Sometimes when these won't suffice you will have to use padding/margin which again is very much safe/acceptable(I don't know what that means here though - however you take it).

Just need to understand that when you have defined a container as `flex` you cannot use few `block` properties like `text-align` etc.

Hope you got the right perspective.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a complete answer!  You really helped me out