# Button to the very edge, delete margin

Tags: html, css

I have a question: How can I do the buttons to the very edge of the blue border while keeping the margin between the buttons? How to delete margin from right and bottom.
I use flexbox and it is work fine but I don't know how to delete this margin.
I would like delete margin which I marked in green,

[image]

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

button {
  margin-right: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS has so-called pseudo-selectors like [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) and [`:nth-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieveing that using flexbox is quite a challenge because there is no built in flexbox feature to have gaps between columns.

[Better way to set distance between flexbox items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626685/better-way-to-set-distance-between-flexbox-items)

However if you would use `grid`, you could easily achieve it.

```css
.container {
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
  <button>Text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! THANK YOU! <3