# How to give space between two rows of products in Angular4

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

In my application I am binding the product and it's details from API response dynamically .Here I have an issue like there is no space between the products when the row count more than one.

Html.

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4 column" *ngFor="let product of products;let i =index;">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250 one">
                <img routerLink="/my-cart" class="img-fluid" [src]="product['IMAGE_PATH_1']" alt="image">
                <img routerLink="/my-cart" class="img-fluid two" [src]="product['IMAGE_PATH_2']" alt="image">
            </div>
            <div class="card-block pt-2">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center card-text">
                    <span>{{product?.ITEM_DESCRIPTION}}</span>
                    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" #productCode value="{{product?.PRODUCT_CODE}}">
                    <p class="font-weight-bold text-primary" >{{product?.PRODUCT_PRICE}} &#8377;</p>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary col-sm-12 corner" routerLink="/my-cart" (click)="getProductCode(productCode.value)">
                    <strong>View Details</strong>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The above code is a separate component (grid component),I just call this component in another component (app component)

```
 <div class="row  container" >
          <app-grid></app-grid>
 </div>
```

Image :

[image]

Can anyone help me to fix this .

Comment: by the way you create nestead `row` remove row class from `<div class="row  container" >'

Comment: @לבנימלכה removed it ,still it shows as in the above image

Comment: of course I said it by the way

Comment: see my answer please

Comment: I think flexbox is the way to go for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626685/better-way-to-set-distance-between-flexbox-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Bootstrap 4 spacing utilities: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

I added `p-3`  **to** `<div class="col-sm-4 column p-3" *ngFor="let product of products;let i =index;">`

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4 column p-3" *ngFor="let product of products;let i =index;">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250 one">
                <img routerLink="/my-cart" class="img-fluid" [src]="product['IMAGE_PATH_1']" alt="image">
                <img routerLink="/my-cart" class="img-fluid two" [src]="product['IMAGE_PATH_2']" alt="image">
            </div>
            <div class="card-block pt-2">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center card-text">
                    <span>{{product?.ITEM_DESCRIPTION}}</span>
                    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" #productCode value="{{product?.PRODUCT_CODE}}">
                    <p class="font-weight-bold text-primary" >{{product?.PRODUCT_PRICE}} &#8377;</p>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary col-sm-12 corner" routerLink="/my-cart" (click)="getProductCode(productCode.value)">
                    <strong>View Details</strong>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ...You saved my time

Comment: happy to help:)