# Create multiple React Elements using one function

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to grid a grid with one function that adds 50px to the top css element for each line created.

```
class Grid extends Component {

  createGrid = () => {
    for (let i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
      return(
        <div style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: i * 5,
          height: 1,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#bfd8e0"
        }}>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default Grid;
```

```
class MainPage extends Grid {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.createGrid()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

How would I render this so it creates x amount of lines for the grid, while also increasing the top css by 50px

Comment: This seems like something you would do with CSS / Flexbox more than something you'd want to do manually inline utilizing the style prop in React.  I would recommend looking at something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626685/better-way-to-set-distance-between-flexbox-items

Comment: To start, you should probably be pushing every element you create to an array and then returning that. Putting return inside of a `for` loop will also exit your function, so currently you're just returning the first element from the first iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a (typical) function, just create another React component that does this.

Something like:

```
class Grid extends Component {
  render() {
    return [...Array(this.props.items)].map((_x, i) => (
      <div
        key={i}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: i * 50,
          height: 1,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#bfd8e0"
        }}
      />
    ))
  }
}

export default Grid;
```

```
class MainPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Grid items={50} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Also, to have each item have `top` increase by `50px` do `top: i * 50`

Runnable demo:

```js
class MainPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Grid items={50} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Grid extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return [...Array(this.props.items)].map((_x, i) => (
      <div
        key={i}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: i * 50,
          height: 1,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#bfd8e0"
        }}
      />
    ))
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainPage />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: you will get this: `Each child in an array should have a unique "key" prop.` I guess. You should also add the unique key to the `div` element in the map function

Comment: @CornelRaiu Already fixed :) Edit: nvm, fixed in snippet but forgot to in code block

Answer (score 0):

For your grid generator, this way you can generate elements and using them in render function:

```
createGrid = () => {
    let grids = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
      grids.push(
        <div style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: i * 5,
          height: 1,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#bfd8e0"
        }}>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return grids;
  }
```

But Always favor [composition over inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance) classes in react components.