# Remove gap between elements in flex layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As shown in the image attached, there is a very large gap between each of my elements and I was to reduce that vertical gap. This is my code so far, but I'm not sure what to add to the CSS to fix the issue. Thanks

```
 </div>
  <div className="flex-container">
    <Email username={username}/>
    <Message username={username}/>
    <Whatsapp username={username}/>
  </div>



 .flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 700px;
  display: block; /* Make the buttons appear below each other */
}
```

[current flex layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp3dR.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to set distance between flexbox items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626685/better-way-to-set-distance-between-flexbox-items)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)