# containers not centring horizontally

Tags: html, css

I've tried multiple things to center my calendars horizontally on the page, adjusting for screen resizing as well. I've already tried multiple things stack overflow questions have suggested. I've tried adding  `display: flex;` `justify-content: center;` to my containers which didnt end up centring my content. I've also tried removing my `flex` settings and setting `display:inline-block` which also fell short. Any ideas on how to center my content horizontally?

```css
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

@font-face {
    font-family: Raleway;
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
}
body {
  position: relative;
}


.container {
  width: 380px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  margin: -100px auto;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 40px #e8e8e8;
  border-radius:20px;
  float:left;
  transform:scale(.25);
  margin-right:-270px;
}
.one, .two {
  width: 18px;
  height: 45px;
  display:block;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px
}
.one {
  left: 80px
}
.two {
  right: 80px
}
.container .fe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #1880c9;
  position: absolute;
  border-top-right-radius:20px;
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
}

.container .sr, .container .sr2, .container .sr3 {
  height: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #ededed;
  
}

.sr{text-align:center;
font-family:raleway;
  Font-size:75px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#2f2e2e;
  
}

.sr span {
 position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container .sr {
  width: 280px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  overflow:hidden;
  top:70px;
  left:50px;
  z-index:3;
  
}
.container .sr2 {
  width: 260px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  top:80px;
  left:60px;
  z-index:2
}
.container .sr3 {
  width: 240px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  top: 90px;
  left: 70px;
  z-index: 1
}
.container .sr p {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #6120ec;
  border-radius: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 22px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.container .sr p:last-child {
  visibility: hidden
}
.container .sr p:first-child {
  visibility: hidden
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="all">
<div class="container">
  <span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span>
  <div class="fe"></div>
  <div class="sr"><span>Mon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sr2"></div>
  <div class="sr3"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span>
  <div class="fe"></div>
  <div class="sr"><span>Tue</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sr2"></div>
  <div class="sr3"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span>
  <div class="fe"></div>
  <div class="sr"><span>Wed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sr2"></div>
  <div class="sr3"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span>
  <div class="fe"></div>
  <div class="sr"><span>Thu</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sr2"></div>
  <div class="sr3"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span>
  <div class="fe"></div>
  <div class="sr"><span>Fri</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sr2"></div>
  <div class="sr3"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span>
  <div class="fe"></div>
  <div class="sr"><span>Sat</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sr2"></div>
  <div class="sr3"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span>
  <div class="fe"></div>
  <div class="sr"><span>Sun</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sr2"></div>
  <div class="sr3"></div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `div align="center"`

Comment: @YT_Xaos doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're shooting yourself in the foot by trying to `transform:scale(.25)` everything. `scale` will change the visible size of things without affecting their layout, which is why you need that huge negative margin to try and fix it.

Problem is, `flex` also uses margin to layout its elements, so everything's gonna get janky.

Also, `display: flex` goes on the container *of your calendar `.container`s*, not `.container` itself (i.e. `.all`).

So all I did here:

- Remove the `transform`
- Divide any raw pixel values by ~4 (I rounded sometimes so double check)
- Add `display:flex` and `justify-content:center` to `.all`
- Add `flex-shrink: 0` to `.container` so the flexbox doesn't try to compress things if they're too small
- Add `margin: auto 5px` to `.container` so there's `10px` of space between calendars (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626685/better-way-to-set-distance-between-flexbox-items) for other ways to do this)

You can play around with different `justify-contents` and other flex styles on `.all` and `.container`. (Also, maybe rename your classes because `.all` is really just a flexbox and `.container` should be like `.calendar`).

```css
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

@font-face {
    font-family: Raleway;
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
}
body {
  position: relative;
}

.all {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: auto 5px;
  width: 95px;
  height: 88px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 40px #e8e8e8;
  border-radius:5px;
}
.one, .two {
  width: 5px;
  height: 12px;
  display:block;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px
}
.one {
  left: 20px
}
.two {
  right: 20px
}
.container .fe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #1880c9;
  position: absolute;
  border-top-right-radius:5px;
  border-top-left-radius:5px;
}

.container .sr, .container .sr2, .container .sr3 {
  height: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #ededed;
  
}

.sr{text-align:center;
font-family:raleway;
  Font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#2f2e2e;
  
}

.sr span {
 position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container .sr {
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  overflow:hidden;
  top:18px;
  left:13px;
  z-index:3;
  
}
.container .sr2 {
  width: 65px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  top:20px;
  left:15px;
  z-index:2
}
.container .sr3 {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  top: 23px;
  left: 18px;
  z-index: 1
}
.container .sr p {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #6120ec;
  border-radius: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.container .sr p:last-child {
  visibility: hidden
}
.container .sr p:first-child {
  visibility: hidden
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="all">
<div class="container">
  <span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span>
  <div class="fe"></div>
  <div class="sr"><span>Mon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sr2"></div>
  <div class="sr3"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span>
  <div class="fe"></div>
  <div class="sr"><span>Tue</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sr2"></div>
  <div class="sr3"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span>
  <div class="fe"></div>
  <div class="sr"><span>Wed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sr2"></div>
  <div class="sr3"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span>
  <div class="fe"></div>
  <div class="sr"><span>Thu</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sr2"></div>
  <div class="sr3"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span>
  <div class="fe"></div>
  <div class="sr"><span>Fri</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sr2"></div>
  <div class="sr3"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span>
  <div class="fe"></div>
  <div class="sr"><span>Sat</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sr2"></div>
  <div class="sr3"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span>
  <div class="fe"></div>
  <div class="sr"><span>Sun</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sr2"></div>
  <div class="sr3"></div>
</div></div>
```

Edit: Also you should think about what happens if the screen is too small. You could just add `flex-wrap: wrap` to `.all` if you want, that seems like an easy solution.

Comment: Wow and I thought it would be a quick fix. Thanks so much for explaining your code, helps a ton.

Comment: By the way, your CSS code is missing a lot of semicolons and you're importing the same font twice times. Also you wrote the `Font-size:18px;` with capital F. Let your CSS code find errors on a W3C CSS validator page.