# Flex gap and flex wrap with percentages

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am constructing a form where the field's width **percentage** is dynamically set by clients.
My first approach was to create a flex container with wrapping enabled and space the fields evenly using `gap: 16px`. To my surprise, `flex-wrap` and `gap` don't behave as I would expect.

```css
main {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: gray;
  
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
  background-color: blue;
}

.first {
  width: 50%;
}

.second {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="second">Second</div>
</main>
```

I expected them to be in the same line and have the gap in-between. This happens when I remove the `flex-wrap`.

The only solution I found was to use `calc(50% - 16px)`, but this is far from ideal. Maybe I'm approaching the problem wrongly?

Comment: 50% + 50% + 16px > 100%

Comment: But this is not the case when `flex-wrap: nowrap`

Comment: I was expecting 50% = (100% - 16px) / 2

Comment: no, width:50% means half the width, gap is not involved there. When you don't allow the wrap, it's a different story and the shrink factor will enter in play (add flex-shrink:0 and you will have an overflow with nowrap)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. The question how to work with percentage boxes, gap and flex is not given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626685/better-way-to-set-distance-between-flexbox-items/27563449#27563449

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Flexbox Gap - gap value affecting width calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68007483/css-flexbox-gap-gap-value-affecting-width-calculation)

Answer (score 3):

This post has the answer.
https://wiryawanadipa.com/blog/calculate-percentage-width-of-flex-items-when-using-gap/

The solution is a formula based in the amount of items per row and the size of the gap:

width: calc((100% / n) - (((n - 1) / n) * g));

where [n = Number of items per row] and [g = Size of gap]

```css
:root {
    --flex-gap: 1rem; /* Variable for gap */
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: var(--flex-gap);
}
.item {
  --flex-items: 1; /* Variable for number of items */
  width: calc((100% / var(--flex-items)) - (((var(--flex-items) - 1) / var(--flex-items)) * var(--flex-gap)));
  padding: 3rem 1rem;
  background-color: #999;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 520px) {
  .item {
    --flex-items: 2; /* Variable for number of items */
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .item {
    --flex-items: 3; /* Variable for number of items */
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .item {
    --flex-items: 4; /* Variable for number of items */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```