# gap between elements inside div

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="input1" style="display:flex">
  <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
    <label class="control-label" id="t" for="totalMV">Total:</label>
    <input id="totalMV" type="number" class="form-control" value="0"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
    <label class="control-label" id="decim" for="decimal">Dec</label>
    <input class="js-range-slider" id="decimal" data-skin="shiny" data-min="0" data-max="1" data-from="0.5" data-step="0.1" data-grid="true" data-grid-num="10" data-grid-snap="false" data-prettify-separator="," data-prettify-enabled="true" data-keyboard="true" data-data-type="number"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to add a gap between elements inside div.
Right now there is no space/gap between these 2 elements. But can we add?

Comment: You can use margin.

Comment: Margin/Padding?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use margin vs padding in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to set distance between flexbox items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626685/better-way-to-set-distance-between-flexbox-items)

Comment: (Check the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58041749/17684809) about gap properties)

Answer (score 2):

since you are already using `flex`, why not utilize its useful `gap` system like this:

```
.input1 {
  gap: 12em;
}
```

```css
.input1 {
  gap: 12em;
}
```

```html
<div class="input1" style="display:flex">
  <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
    <label class="control-label" id="t" for="totalMV">Total:</label>
    <input id="totalMV" type="number" class="form-control" value="0" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
    <label class="control-label" id="decim" for="decimal">Dec</label>
    <input class="js-range-slider" id="decimal" data-skin="shiny" data-min="0" data-max="1" data-from="0.5" data-step="0.1" data-grid="true" data-grid-num="10" data-grid-snap="false" data-prettify-separator="," data-prettify-enabled="true" data-keyboard="true"
      data-data-type="number" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `column-gap` attribute on the outer div:

```css
div.input1 {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding who will align elements inside div or you can use margin to align your div.

```css
.shiny-input-container{
padding-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input1" style="display:flex">
  <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
    <label class="control-label" id="t" for="totalMV">Total:</label>
    <input id="totalMV" type="number" class="form-control" value="0"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
    <label class="control-label" id="decim" for="decimal">Dec</label>
    <input class="js-range-slider" id="decimal" data-skin="shiny" data-min="0" data-max="1" data-from="0.5" data-step="0.1" data-grid="true" data-grid-num="10" data-grid-snap="false" data-prettify-separator="," data-prettify-enabled="true" data-keyboard="true" data-data-type="number"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="input1" style="display:flex">
  <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
    <label class="control-label" id="t" for="totalMV">Total:</label>
    <input id="totalMV" type="number" class="form-control" value="0"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
    <label class="control-label" id="decim" for="decimal">Dec</label>
    <input class="js-range-slider" id="decimal" data-skin="shiny" data-min="0" data-max="1" data-from="0.5" data-step="0.1" data-grid="true" data-grid-num="10" data-grid-snap="false" data-prettify-separator="," data-prettify-enabled="true" data-keyboard="true" data-data-type="number"/>
  </div>
</div>
```